# What was the point of bringing Ziesha from the future?

Tags: love-story-2050

Once the time machine was completed, Karan expressed a desire to go back in time and rescue his fiance, Sana. Instead, they travel *forward* in time, and instead meet Ziesha.

> Eventually, we find out that Zeisha is Sana reincarnated, and eventually chooses to return to Karan's time with him.

Why didn't Dr. Khanna help Karan by going backward in time? Why go through all the trouble of going to the future

> which only worked out because they happened to find Zeisha and restore her memories?

Comment: Meta Discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/is-community-mistaken-about-too-localized-vtc-cause

Comment: Downvoters and commenters - this is a perfectly legitimate question. You can use time machine to achieve your goal in 2 time directions, and the latter seems completely harder. Why was that choice made? And this is 100% crystal clear from the questions, without ANY knowledge of the movie.

Comment: @DVK Except for possible paradoxes.  Sachin, Wikipedia doesn't give much information, why did they decide to go to the future in the first place, instead of the past like Karan wanted to?

Comment: @Izkata No, Wikipedia doesn't give this info. Plus, going to the future is one thing and deciding to seduce a celebrity within 30 days is another thing...

Comment: @SachinShekhar It is relevant to possible answers involving temporal paradoxes.  DVK could be wrong, and saving Sana would have been outright impossible.

Comment: @Izkata Temporal paradoxes should exist in both time directions, not one.

Comment: @SachinShekhar The possibility exists either way, but the events in the movie should tell us for sure whether one would be created by saving Sana ([The grandfather paradox in particular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox))

Comment: Having just stumbled upon this Q, wouldn't it be better if the body of the Q (if not its title) included the title of the work in question, and possibly an IMDB or similar link? Keeping the title of the work in the tag doesn't really help quickly identifying the topic.